# How to re-generate an unresolved git merge file

Tags: git, merge

In the middle of editing an unmerged file to resolve merge conflicts, I decided to start from scratch on the one file. How can I re-generate the original unresolved file with the standard markers. There can be other files that are already fixed and staged, and yet others waiting to be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout -m <file-name>
```